# Get all published posts in Wordpress, performance issues due to long result set

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to build a array like this:

```
$arrPosts = array(
    thePostID => "The Post Title"
)
```

I'm doing as follow:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'published',
        //'post_type' => get_post_types('post', 'opinion')
    )
);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $article[] = [
        $post->ID => $post->title
    ];
}
```

But it takes a long time to process which is not suitable (I had to set `define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT','1024M')` which is a lot of memory). I need to get only posts from that are post and opinion custom post type.

Does any knows a better way to achieve this?

Comment: By default, WordPress comes with various feeds. RSS feeds for example. Easy to implement in PHP.

Comment: @alib_15 what? feeds? How this help on this?

Comment: Which Wordpress theme did you use for your site? http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wp_query()` like this,

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'orderby'   => 'title',
              'order'     => 'ASC',
              'post_status' => 'publish', //here you can retrieve posts that are published
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = array();
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $posts['thePostID '] =  get_the_title() ; //change appropiately
    }

} else {
    // no posts found
}
print_r($posts);
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```